# Как динамически выделить память в операционной системе DOS используя ассемблер TASM?

Tags: ассемблер, динамические-массивы, dos

Как выделить память из кучи на dos  ассемблере, используя TASM. Как создать динамический массив?

Comment: в dos по моему нет системной кучи, а RTL-ы языков её сами организуют в доступном пространстве

Comment: Лайфхак - надо написать malloc или calloc или new на языке Си или C++, потом странслировать его транслятором под DOS с получением ассемблерного листинга и потом поглядеть, во что транслятор разворачивает этот malloc или calloc или new. :-) Не благодарите. :-)

Comment: вообще-то DOS сложно назвать OS, это такая резидентная в памяти библиотека ввода/вывода

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть прерывание `int 21h` для работы с основными функцими MS DOS. Там есть и функция выделения памяти и ее освобождения.

Вот из справочника по прерыванию 21H

- 48Н Выделение памяти из свободного пространства.
- 49Н Освобождений выделенной памяти.

Описание и подробные примеры, наверно можно найти в интернете.

Comment: да, но надо понимать, что это просто память сразу за запущенной программой, это не совсем системный heap, подозреваю, что автор вопроса не понимает что в dos не задействован MMU даже если он есть

Comment: Да, нужен хип, получается хип нужно реализовать самостоятельно?

Comment: не совсем понятно что именно требуется; возможно подойдет вариант использования стека ? push/pop и sp